# Session Value doesnot retain for selection box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-value

[Here is Picture For my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I66q.png)

I have populated the select box data dynamically and after setting in session those values must  be selected even the page reloads

The code that populates the select box options is using ajax get method

```
 else if (value.sourceType > 0) {
        $('#SOURCE_TYPE').append('<option data-ng-value="' + 
        value.sourceName +'">'+ value.sourceName + '</option>');
 }
```

1.The selected session value should place in the selection box

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngMessages']);
app.controller("quotationController",
  function($scope,$window) {

     $scope.quotation =[];
    $scope.contactId = null;
    $scope.quotation.drpContactType=$window.sessionStorage.getItem( 'drpContactType' );
    $scope.quotation.sourceType = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('sourceType');

    $scope.submit = function(){
      $window.sessionStorage.setItem('drpContactType',$scope.quotation.drpContactType);
      $window.sessionStorage.setItem('sourceType', $scope.quotation.sourceType);

    };

    fnendtmotoronload();
  });
 function fnendtmotoronload() {
var status = true;
var contactId = document.getElementById("CONTACT_TYPE").value;
var CONTEXT_PATH = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/';

$.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : CONTEXT_PATH + "quotationDrop",
  data : contactId,
  contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(index, value) {
      if (value.contactType > 0) {
        $('#CONTACT_TYPE').append(
            '<option data-ng-value="' + value.contactName + '">'
                       + value.contactName + '</option>');
      } else if (value.sourceType > 0) {
        $('#SOURCE_TYPE').append(
            '<option data-ng-value="' + value.sourceName + '">'
                + value.sourceName + '</option>');
      } 
    });

  }
});
return status; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select ng-model="quotation.sourceType" ng-option="{{quotation.sourceType}}" required id="SOURCE_TYPE"
  class="form-control">
  <!-- <option selected="selected" value="0">--SELECT--</option> -->
</select>
```

**Data From DB**

```
{
  "contactType": 0,
  "contactActiveStatus": "\u0000",
  "createdBy": 0,
  "sourceType": 2,
  "accountCode": 0,
  "sourceName": "ADMIN",
  "newIcNo": 0,
  "businessRegNo": 0,
  "oldIcNo": 0,
  "quotationID": 0,
  "nameddriversno": 0,
  "namedage": 0,
  "extracoverageid": 0,
  "mpaid": 0
```

},

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not how AngularJS works. Forget about generating DOM elements using jQuery. Even forget that jQuery exists. Use AngularJS templates. Read the documentation of select, ngOptions.

Comment: that works fine............. my issue is when is go back to same page those value i submitted before must load in the select box like edit mode in the **image** you can see the ng-options is set to ADMIN fromthe session.... but the select box does not changes to ADMIN. @JBNizet

Comment: There must be a problem in your code then. But you didn't post it. So How could I know what to change? All I know is the 3 lines of code you posted, which are definitely not correct.

Comment: I have Updated the code ... Instead of assigning the data from db to json array i have used the dom ajax to set select box options @JBNizet

Comment: And that is completely, completely wrong, as I just said twice. Forget jQuery. Don't do **any** DOM manipulation. That's not how Angular works. Read the documentation instead.

Comment: ok i will rewrite the code ........ thank you @JBNizet